# PThreads.Consumer-Producer! printing in different files

Tags: c, pthreads, consumer, producer

i m trying to implement the producer - consumer with threads.In my code below is working well except of the point where i try to print into 2 files.(one for prod and one for cons).I use fclose(stdout) . when i delete it inside producer then the print in  producer file is ok but consumers no.when i deleted at all then all of the data printed into the consumer file.My question is what i should try to make the  prints correctly( i need consumer to print in cons.out.txt and producer in prod_out.txt) .Also i didnt include check for threads to make it simple but it works well.
    #include "head.h"

```
circular_buffer cb;  
pthread_mutex_t lock; 
pthread_cond_t cond;  


char * data[6]; //is the data taken from cmd(argv[0-6]) first one is the program the other are parameters


int main(int argc , char *argv[])  { 
    validate(argv,argc); //if command arguments are valid  go on
    for(int i=0; i < argc; i++){
         data[i]=argv[i]; //copy argv array to data array 
    }

    cb_init(&cb,10,sizeof(int)); //initialization of circular buffer for 10 nodes + size of int each node 
    pthread_t cons, prod;  
    void *consumer(), *producer();

    int rc = pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    rc = pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    int id[]={1,2}; //prod id is 1 and cons 2

    rc = pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, &id[0]);
        rc = pthread_create(&cons, NULL, consumer, &id[1]);

    rc=pthread_join(prod, NULL); 
    rc=pthread_join(cons, NULL); 

    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    cb_free(&cb); //free allocated memory which is alocated in head
    return 1;

 }  
void *consumer(void * id){
     int  thread_id= *((int*)id); //cast to (int)
     int file;  
     FILE * fp2 = fopen("./cons_out.txt","wb"); //creates new file with "cons_out.txt" name
     int i =10; 
     while(i > 0){
         i--;
         pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 

         while(isEmpty(&cb)){
            int rc = pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
         }//end while

         int item=0; // item that will be consumed
         cb_pop_front(&cb,&item);
         file = open("./cons_out.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0777 );//open file as new   
         if( file == -1 ) {//fail to open file
                perror("./cons_out.txt");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
         }
         fclose(stdout);
         dup2( file, STDOUT_FILENO); //change redirections
         printf("Consumer %d : %d\n",thread_id,item); //print output to file

         pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 

     } //end while

         return NULL;
} //end consumer() 

void *producer(void * id){
     int  thread_id= *((int*)id); //cast to (*int)
     int file1; 
     FILE * fp1 = fopen("./prod_in.txt","wb"); //creates new file with "prod_in.txt" name
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ //it produce 10 numbers 
         pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 

         while(isFull(&cb)){
            int rc = pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
         }//end while

         int seed=1;
         int item=rand(); // item of this producer
         cb_push_back(&cb,&item); 
         file1 = open("./prod_in.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0777 );//open file as new   
         if( file1 == -1 ) {//fail to open file
            perror("./prod_in.txt");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
         }
         fclose(stdout);
         dup2( file1, STDOUT_FILENO); //change output 
         printf("Producer %i : %i\n",thread_id,item); //print output to file

         pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
         } //end for 

         return NULL;

} //end Producer();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one open file table for your whole process, shared by all threads in it.  There is one entry in that table for the standard output, and your producer and consumer are contending for it.  It's not clear why.

I'm inclined to think that the immediate reason for your troubles is that `fclose()`ing the `stdout` stream releases the stream-level resources, especially the buffer and state-tracking details.  `open()`ing a file descriptor does not provide those, nor does `dup2()`ing a file descriptor into a `FILE` object representing a closed stream.

But it baffles me why you are making it so hard.  Why in the world muck with duping file descriptors?  Your producer and consumer already `fopen()` the wanted output files, thereby each obtaining its own stream connected with the appropriate file (`fp1` and `fp2`).  It seems to me that all you need to do, then, is to write to those streams via `fprintf()`, *etc*., instead of going to a lot of trouble to be able to use `printf()` instead.

That would be more efficient, too, since you oughtn't to need to keep opening and closing the files.  Open each once, at the beginning, as you already do, and close each once, at the end, which you presently *fail* to do.